# Expo Linear Gradient transparent is showing up blackish

Tags: react-native, gradient, expo

I'm trying to get a bottom to top white to transparent-white transition in my React Native screen using Expo Linear Gradients:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient.html

I copied the second example and flipped it around, and made it white instead of black. But now the "transparent" the white is supposed to fade in to is darker that the white is, see below:

[image]

The transparent actually is see through so that's good but is there a way to give it a white hue?

Code here:

```
     <LinearGradient
         colors={[ 'transparent', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)']}
         style={{
           position: 'absolute',
           left: 0,
           right: 0,
           bottom: 0,
           height: 200,
         }}
       />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because `transparent` is equal to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Try using `rgba(255,255,255,0)` instead of transparent to get a white to white transition

The w3 spec defines transparent as `transparent black` as can be read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparent)

Comment: Yeah, it's an easy one to miss, not obvious how transparent should be defined

Answer (score 8):

I actually found my own answer. "transparent" apparently translates to black-transparent, to get white just specify an rgba() in the white channel like so:

```
<LinearGradient
    colors={[ 'rgba(255,255,255,0)', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)']}
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        height: 80,
    }}
/>
```